# Is it possible to setup Mindeo MP725 scanner via virtual COM port programmatically?

Tags: serial-port, hardware, barcode-scanner

Mindeo MP725 scanner [manual](http://www.mindeo.cn/download.php?id=796) states that scanner can be adjusted via scanning special barcodes. It also contains example with %NMUGD barcode and says that it is equivalent to command 0x16 0x4D 0x0D 0x25 0x4E 0x4D 0x55 0x47 0x44 0x2E via COM port. Looks like code

```
serialPort.WriteLine($"{(char)0x16}M\r%NMUGD.\r");
```

is working. Some special barcodes can be translated into byte commands in similar way, e.g. %%%VER - code

```
serialPort.WriteLine($"{(char)0x16}M\r%%%VER.");
```

works flawlessly. But I failed to translate most of other special barcodes like %0503D00%. Scanning of such barcode turns off scanner's beeper but code

```
serialPort.WriteLine($"{(char)0x16}M\r%0503D00%.\r");
```

has no effect. Has anyone worked with this scanner via COM port? Is it possible to setup it programmatically without scanning special barcodes? If possible, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. We should transmit barcodes like %0503D00% without percent chars, i.e.

```
serialPort.WriteLine($"{(char)0x16}M\r0503D00.\r");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add, after an executable command is sent, you need to get a response from the scanner, otherwise the new settings may not work.
As an example, wrote in python:

```
ser.write('\x16M\r0503D00.\r'.encode())
time.sleep(0.2)
resp = ser.read(100)
print(resp)
```